# What does [co] mean in the "rm -rf filename[co]" command?

Tags: command-line, bash, rm

Let's say I have two files in `/tmp`:

```
root@ubuntu:~# touch /tmp/hello.{pyc,py}

root@ubuntu:~# ls /tmp/
hello.py  hello.pyc
```

Now, lets run `rm -rf` command with [co] option

```
root@ubuntu:~# rm -rf /tmp/hello.py[co]

root@ubuntu:~# ls /tmp/
hello.py
```

Can someone please explain what's happening here? What is the `[co]` parameter? How can we make it work for other extensions? Say I have `foo.js` and `foo.coffee` files, can we do something like `rm -rf /tmp/foo.coffe[co]` to delete the `/tmp/foo.js`?

Comment: There's no need for `-rf` there, as those are neither directories (`--recursive`), nor unwritable (`--force`).

Comment: There's no need for `-rf` and there's no need to be doing things as root. Especially if the things in question involve `rm -rf`.

Comment: Guys, its just sample commands to explain the problem. The actual question was about `[co]` shell glob. Thanks.

Comment: @aneeshep If someone's looking down the barrel of a gun and asking how to clean it, do you first warn them about looking down the barrel or tell them how to clean it?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`[co]` isn't a parameter to the `rm` command - it's a *shell glob* that matches a pattern equal to a single character from the set `[co]` - in other words, it matches either a `c` or an `o` a the end of the filename. From `man bash`:

```
[...]  Matches any one of the enclosed characters
```

To match both `foo.coffee` and `foo.js`, since the suffixes don't contain any common substrings at all, the best you could do is `foo.*` which would match *any* filename starting with `foo.` Instead you could use *brace expansion* e.g.

```
rm foo.{coffee,js}
```

Comment: Yup got it. I missed the basic concept in bash ;). Thank you :)

Comment: _search patterns_ like `[abc]` or `*` will _search for files_ while `{}` won't. go to /tmp, type `echo nya[ab]; echo nya{a,b}`, then `touch nyaa` and again `echo nya[ab]; echo nya{a,b}`

Answer (score 16):

It is not a parameter but a collection of letters (or a "shell glob"). This is the same:

```
rm -rf /tmp/hello.py[co]
```

is the same as

```
rm -rf /tmp/hello.pyc
rm -rf /tmp/hello.pyo
```

---

Similar ...

```
rm -rf /tmp/hello.py[c-o]
```

would delete anything from `/tmp/hello.pyc` up to and including `/tmp/hello.pyo` following ASCII ordering.

```
rm -rf /tmp/hello.py[ab][cd]
```

would remove ...

```
rm -rf /tmp/hello.pyac
rm -rf /tmp/hello.pyad
rm -rf /tmp/hello.pybc
rm -rf /tmp/hello.pybd
```

---

> say, i have foo.js and foo.coffee files, can we do something like `rm -rf /tmp/foo.coffe[co]` to delete the `/tmp/foo.js`.

You can make rather fancy methods but for those 2 files I'd just remove them with 1 command for each. Another example getting as close as possible to those 2 files...

```
rm /tmp/foo.[cj]*
```

would remove files like this ...

```
rm /tmp/foo.c*
rm /tmp/foo.j*
```

so it would include far more than just these 2 files.

Comment: If I am not misunderstanding, you get one invocation of `rm -rf` with all of the matches, not many invocations each with one match.

Comment: yes. but not the intent of the rm's i added. those are just to show what would be needed to be typed as an equivalent ;-)

Answer (score 1):

It's a shell glob, similar to wildcards `*` and `?` ...in bash, the filename pattern `*.[co]` matches all filenames that finish with `.c` or `.o`.

The difference with `*.[co]` versus `*.c *.o` or `*.{c,o}` is that the two latter patterns will expand to a dummy `*.o` if no `.o` files exist in the directory, while the `*.[co]` version won't.

Shell globs are useful for doing file operations in a non-case-sensitive way. For example, if you have a bunch of files with filenames that end with `jpg`, `JPG`, `Jpg`, `JPg`, etc... and you want to remove all of them, you can do:

```
rm *.[Jj][Pp][Gg]
```